# Audit two different tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have a form with data. Any changes or insertion , those data should be updated in tow different tables like name, salary in one table and address, mail id in another table.

Like the example above i have several columns in both tables.

Now i want to audit the table. So i think i have to create a view for the two tables and set up a trigger for the view. Is it correct?.

And also i need to know only the affected columns. How to get the only affected columns?

Please suggest me a solution.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to let the system handle all that grunt work for you - depending on the SQL Server version you're using:

- [How to: Use SQL Server Change Tracking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc305322.aspx) (as of SQL Server 2008)
- [Introduction to SQL Server change tracking](http://www.mostlydevelopers.com/mostlydevelopers/blog/post/2009/10/03/Introduction-to-SQL-Server-Change-Tracking.aspx)
- [Understanding SQL Server Audit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280386.aspx) (as of SQL Server 2008 R2)
- [Articles for SQL Server Auditing](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/audit/index.aspx) (various versions)

If you really must handle all the work yourself, you need to get familiarized with triggers - read up on them in [Data Points: Exploring SQL Server Triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164047.aspx).

Inside your trigger code, you have two "pseudo-tables":

- `Inserted` is the table holding the values being inserted (in an INSERT trigger) or the new values (in an UPDATE trigger)
- `Deleted` is the table holding the values being deleted (in a DELETE trigger) or the old values (in an UPDATE trigger)

With those two pseudo-tables, you can get access to all data you might need.

Comment: What is BOL ? Is anyway related to this? I got this from this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684293/change-data-capture-or-change-tracking-same-as-traditional-audit-trail-table

Comment: @Manoj: BOL = Books Online - Online SQL Server documentation (MSDN Library)